# Url list problems

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with url patterns, you can see them below.

I can connect to the only one category called "Python" (`slug = 'python'`). Others like "Django", "Other categories", "Myown" links are not working, they're showing me 404 errors like below.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango/category/myown
Using the URLconf defined in tang_w_djang.urls, Django tried these URL 
patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^$ [name='index']
^rango/ ^$ [name='index']
^rango/ ^about/$ [name='about']
^rango/ ^add_category/$ [name='add_category']
^rango/ ^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$ [name='show_category']
^rango/ ^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/add_page/$  [name='add_page']
The current URL, rango/category/myown, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: Try `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango/category/myown/` with a trailing slash. I'm not sure it will work, because normally Django automatically redirects and adds the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL pattern `^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$` has a trailing slash.

Therefore, you should use the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango/category/myown/` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango/category/myown/` to view the category.

If you the [common middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.common) enabled and `APPEND_SLASH=True` in your settings, then Django should redirect from `/rango/category/myown` to `/rango/category/myown/`. See the docs for more info.

Comment: If I use APPEND_SLASH I have conflict with my add_page function in views.(_Runtime error_)


("_You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/rango/category/myown/add_page/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings._")


I solve this editing the **URL** patterns like this:


'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/?$'


adding the question mark.
But your comment above helped me.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I would recommend removing the question mark, and changing the form to include the trailing slash as the error message says.